# Nav list-item issue on ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, navigation

I'm having an issue with my rounded navigation, the first list item appears to have a huge gap on the right.

I have a list of links inside an UL each have their own class so I could set a background icon to them. Now the first link has a background with rounded corners.

I used relative to push to left so it would have that rounded effect for the hover and active states on the homepage and hover for when i'm on other pages.

Now it all works fine in new browsers apart from IE8 and probably older versions.

I've put it on JSFiddle to make it easier to view. Sorry for the unnecessary CSS properties.

http://jsfiddle.net/datastream/Gta3h/2/

Thanks.

Comment: [That looks fine](http://fiddle.jshell.net/datastream/Gta3h/2/show/light/) in IE8. What doctype does your actual page have? Also, are you using any kind of `X-UA-Compatible` header?

Comment: Havent added any doctype or anything its just strictly html and css. you should get any idea if you look at my jsfiddle link in IE8

Comment: This is your jsFiddle link in IE8: http://i.imgur.com/zOTpV.png - it looks fine as far as I can see.

Comment: Hint: jsFiddle is adding a doctype for you, which is confusing matters. Posting a link to your actual live page (not jsFiddle) is the easiest thing you can do right now.

Comment: It works when i add a document type. Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I will know for future sites by not forgetting to add them :(

Comment: If you're happy that this is fixed after adding the doctype, you can mark the answer I was halfway through writing (but then I saw your happy comment) as accepted.

Comment: OT: You also have a 1px background issue on the bottom of your navbar in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome on OSX; the list items aren't tall enough to fully cover the `<ul>` background image, adding `#topNav2 li { height: 15px; }` fixes that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my best guess at what's going on.

You said:

> Havent added any doctype or anything
>   its just strictly html and css

If you haven't added a doctype, then IE will be in [Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) - this is bad.

---

Just saw your comment: so apparently the answer was to add a doctype to bring IE out of Quirks mode.

Comment: @hirtydot Thanks that did fix the problem, although now my problem actually occurs in IE7 even with the doctype. I think I should make another question for this?

Comment: Yeah, I think you should. You'll get everyone viewing it again because it's at the top of the list, and the problem is clearer now: "How to fix my navigation to work in IE7?"